# Redis - Using Incr value in a transaction

Tags: node.js, transactions, redis

Is it possible to use `multi.incr(value)` with `multi.hmset`?

I mean:

```
var name = 'Josh';
var multi = client.multi();
multi.incr('id'); // incr => 1
multi.hmset('user:' + <need incr value here>, 'username', name);
// I want multi.hmset('user:1', 'username', 'Josh');
multi.exec(function(err,data){ .. });
```

My objective is to increment 'id', and then set it to a user id in a transaction. I have read, that i need to do `client.watch('id')`, but i don't understand how to use it.

PD: Please, post your answer with code, is the best way :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<s>The accepted answer above is unnecessarily complicated.  You do not need to use a multi or watch in this circumstance.  INCR is already atomic, and is designed for this exact scenario.</s> Edit: Thanks to Itamar Haber & robe007 for getting the accepted answer changed. :)

You can simply do this:

```
var name = 'Josh';
client.incr('id', function(err, id) {
    client.hmset('user:' + id, 'username', name);
});
```

By doing the above, INCR automatically locks the "id" key, increments it for you, unlocks it, and returns it to you.  Thus, there is no way for anyone to get a duplicate user id using the code above.  It also has the benefit of never really being able to fail, unlike WATCH/GET, where you'd have to check for failures and run your queries again if they failed.

Comment: But it's not transaction safe. I can't see this to be an answer to the initial question regarding using incr in a transaction, since this receipt does not work in a transaction

Comment: Does it read value and then unlock or unlock and then read? If it were to unlock before reading new value the value might change again before reading.